# Need help using Bus Pirate SPI with Rspberry pi

Tags: gpio, spi

I am using a Pi 3 I recently acquired for a project at work. I am pretty new to most of this electronics, so a large pool of ignorance may follow. Also, if you are not familiar with the tool i used on the pi, what alternative way do you suggest to generate an SPI byte string from the Pi?

I want to just get a taste for SPI commutation, and so I decided to do some reading and writing with the bus pirate and the [spincl](http://ipsolutionscorp.com/raspberry-pi-spi-utility/) command lines utility for the pi. My SPI settings on the Bus Pirate are as follows 2. 125KHz 1. Idle low 2. Active to Ideal 2. End 1. CS 2.Normal
My command to the pi was such:

```
sudo spincl -m0 -c11 -s0 -p0 2 0x5C 0x5C
```

so now if i enter 'r' (read) on the BP, I should read "0x5C 0x5C" right? it is only reading 0x00. Just to be sure, I tried the spincl command with all modes and polarities. But no luck so far.
Any advice would be very helpful. If you are not familiar with spincl, what is the easiest way in your view to test SPI communication on the Raspberry Pi?

Thanks!